# Django group by a query set and multiply with another field

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have this kind of model :

```
class OrderProducts(models.Model):
    product  = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

I need to count how many OrderProducts have the same product. It's working with this line :

```
ordersProduct = OrderProducts.objects.prefetch_related('product_set')\
   .filter(my-filter)\
   .values('product','product__title')\
   .annotate(total=Count('product'))\
   .order_by('-total')
```

This line works and I know how many same OrdersProduct I have. But, I need to add for each OrdersProduct the total quantity with quantity of each orderProduct.

If I have got 3 times the same OrderProduct with the same product inside, I would like to know the quantity (total) with each quantity of this 3 queries.

Thanks !

Edit :

It's working with this :

```
ordersProduct = OrderProducts.objects.prefetch_related('product_set')\
    .filter('my-filter')\
    .values('product','product__title')\
    .annotate(total_ordered=models.Sum('quantity'),num_orders=models.Count('product'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
class OrderProducts(models.Model):
    product  = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orders')

Product.objects.annotate(total_ordered=models.Sum('orders__quantity'),
                         num_orders=models.Count('orders__id'))
```

Comment: My pleasure. If it worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted, so that the others can rely on it.

Comment: I thank you for this answer. But I don't think it's what I'm looking for. I need to add each quantity of each query grouped. To have the number of each Product grouped and know the total quantity of all this same query.

Comment: Could you explain what does "number of each Product grouped" mean? Do you have any `ProductGroup` or something? Extending your post with all related models would also be of great help.

Comment: Well, that's fantastic, but we can't imagine how those numbers should be computed. Could you at least give us the result you want to see? Some example data and the query result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: lol, sorry It's difficult... I need two numbers. The first one is the total quantity of each same queries with the same product. So with the above code I know how many products I have got. But, I need the total quantity for each product grouped, e.g : OP1.create(product="test",quantity=4); OP2.create(product="test",quantity=1); I will have a total of 2 for this same product (the product "TEST") because I have got two queries with the same product. But I need to count how many total quantity I have got for this same product with each quantity, in this case 4 + 1 = 5. Do you understand ?

Comment: I feel I'm starting to do ). Check the updated answer. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, I change a little bit but it's working now... :-) See my EDIT ;-) Thx again !